# Excel - Vlookup repeating values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, multiple-select

I've a huge excel table (more than 100000 lines) and I need to find the values that appear according to a dropdown list.

So I've implemented a VLOOKUP funcion:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D$1;'table'!A2:$O$100000;2;FALSE); "-")
```

But the problem is that the function keeps repeating the same value, so for exemple, if there's only one appearence of a specific data, the funcion will repeat it has long the funcion exists.

I want to change it so if the value only appears one time, the funcion will only return one value, if it appears two times, the funcion only return two values, while the rest of the data only shows a - sign.

Example:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRZqw.png)

Comment: When you say *"return two values"*, do you want the two values in a **single cell** or in **separate cells** ??

Comment: Hi gary, separeted cells. Like in a row:                                                                       78888
78888
78888
78888
While there's only one 78888 value

Answer (score 2):

Try it as,

```
=iferror(index('table'!b:b, aggregate(15, 6, row($2:$99999)/('table'!a$2:a$99999=d$1), row(1:1))), "-")
```

Fill down for the second, third, etc. Make sure you at least as many rows of formulas as the maximum number of any single value.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jeeped, I've tried the formula but it did't worked, the formula just show the value " - ", can you help me? There's anything that needs to be changed on the formula?

Comment: Sorry, you failed to supply sample data and I cannot see your computer's screen. I can assure that it was tested and works at my end as you can see by my recently added image.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, I've added an example.